# Why do some figures sparkle?

Tags: pokemon-duel

I've noticed that some Pokemon have sparkles when viewed in the library or on the board - e.g.

[image]

Why? And does this make any difference to a non-sparkled version?

Comment: Isn't that the Shiny variant in Pokemon duel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following this link to [a list of figures](http://serebii.net/duel/figures.shtml) given by Vemonus, it seems that all Rare (R) figures have sparkles.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that that's just the way the figures look for some Pokémon.

Based on threads like [this one](https://www.reddit.com/r/pokemonduel/comments/5tub11/shiny_charizard_concept/) that mention the lack of shiny Pokémon in Pokémon Duel, it looks like this is just the standard figure for Jolteon.

> I'm surprised there's no "foils" in this game. Shiny color palettes and some sparklies would be a good way to bling out a deck.

I noticed there are a few others that also have sparkles on the [Serebii page with all of the figures listed](http://serebii.net/duel/figures.shtml).

From that list, [Jolteon](http://serebii.net/duel/figures/188-jolteon.shtml) and [Vaporeon](http://serebii.net/duel/figures/187-vaporeon.shtml) both appear to have sparkles on their figures.

As mentioned by @Gremlin, these appear to be all of the figures with rarity "Rare". After looking back at the list, I can confirm this.

The following 49 Pokémon have sparkling figures:

- [Armaldo](http://serebii.net/duel/figures/3-armaldo.shtml)
- [Murkrow](http://serebii.net/duel/figures/17-murkrow.shtml)
- [Steelix](http://serebii.net/duel/figures/21-steelix.shtml)
- [Luxray](http://serebii.net/duel/figures/25-luxray.shtml)
- [Heracross](http://serebii.net/duel/figures/36-heracross.shtml)
- [Meowth](http://serebii.net/duel/figures/40-meowth.shtml)
- [Skarmory](http://serebii.net/duel/figures/43-skarmory.shtml)
- [Machamp](http://serebii.net/duel/figures/45-machamp.shtml)
- [Wobbuffet](http://serebii.net/duel/figures/51-wobbuffet.shtml)
- [Dratini](http://serebii.net/duel/figures/56-dratini.shtml)
- [Eevee](http://serebii.net/duel/figures/57-eevee.shtml)
- [Pinsir](http://serebii.net/duel/figures/59-pinsir.shtml)
- [Absol](http://serebii.net/duel/figures/68-absol.shtml)
- [Salamence](http://serebii.net/duel/figures/70-salamence.shtml)
- [Gabite](http://serebii.net/duel/figures/77-gabite.shtml)
- [Drapion](http://serebii.net/duel/figures/91-drapion.shtml)
- [Goodra](http://serebii.net/duel/figures/98-goodra.shtml)
- [Lapras](http://serebii.net/duel/figures/102-lapras.shtml)
- [Pikachu](http://serebii.net/duel/figures/104-pikachu.shtml)
- [Sneasel](http://serebii.net/duel/figures/107-sneasel.shtml)
- [Electabuzz](http://serebii.net/duel/figures/117-electabuzz.shtml)
- [Tyranitar](http://serebii.net/duel/figures/118-tyranitar.shtml)
- [Tentacruel](http://serebii.net/duel/figures/120-tentacruel.shtml)
- [Banette](http://serebii.net/duel/figures/126-banette.shtml)
- [Slaking](http://serebii.net/duel/figures/127-slaking.shtml)
- [Jigglypuff](http://serebii.net/duel/figures/135-jigglypuff.shtml)
- [Onix](http://serebii.net/duel/figures/146-onix.shtml)
- [Gastly](http://serebii.net/duel/figures/153-gastly.shtml)
- [Gyarados](http://serebii.net/duel/figures/163-gyarados.shtml)
- [Flygon](http://serebii.net/duel/figures/173-flygon.shtml)
- [Sylveon](http://serebii.net/duel/figures/176-sylveon.shtml)
- [Leafeon](http://serebii.net/duel/figures/179-leafeon.shtml)
- [Vaporeon](http://serebii.net/duel/figures/187-vaporeon.shtml)
- [Jolteon](http://serebii.net/duel/figures/188-jolteon.shtml)
- [Wigglytuff](http://serebii.net/duel/figures/206-wigglytuff.shtml)
- [Shiftry](http://serebii.net/duel/figures/214-shiftry.shtml)
- [Kirlia](http://serebii.net/duel/figures/215-kirlia.shtml)
- [Ralts](http://serebii.net/duel/figures/217-ralts.shtml)
- [Glaceon](http://serebii.net/duel/figures/223-glaceon.shtml)
- [Weavile](http://serebii.net/duel/figures/225-weavile.shtml)
- [Flareon](http://serebii.net/duel/figures/248-flareon.shtml)
- [Magmar](http://serebii.net/duel/figures/250-magmar.shtml)
- [Umbreon](http://serebii.net/duel/figures/256-umbreon.shtml)
- [Hydreigon](http://serebii.net/duel/figures/264-hydreigon.shtml)
- [Dragonair](http://serebii.net/duel/figures/280-dragonair.shtml)
- [Whimsicott](http://serebii.net/duel/figures/298-whimsicott.shtml)
- [Gothitelle](http://serebii.net/duel/figures/305-gothitelle.shtml)
- [Reuniclus](http://serebii.net/duel/figures/308-reuniclus.shtml)
- [Druddigon](http://serebii.net/duel/figures/312-druddigon.shtml)

Comment: It seems like it's all of the rare figures, no?

Comment: @Gremlin, you're right. I provided the full list of these.